# User access to own contact record, forwarding upon login

Tags: wordpress, profile, dashboard, user-account

Is there a document that describes how best to setup the security in CiviCRM on WordPress so that a user can login and access their own record? I have read much of the documentation that is in the forum and in the help but nothing that seems consistently in one place from step to step.

The part that seems to be missing is how to forward the person logging in to their own record, rather than to a page where they have to search or find their record. I'm not a programmer so I am assuming this must require some code that I can't find reference to. Any links anyone can share?

Answer (score 5):

When a user is logged in their information is auto populated in profile forms. So when they go to event registrations, donation pages, etc. their info is listed in the profile fields. If they make changes this information is updated in CiviCRM.

You can create a profile for editing and insert it into a WordPress page via a short code with the edit option and direct the user there after login. You may want to restrict access to that page to logged in users. The 'Members' plugin in WordPress does a good job of restricting access by user role.

Comment: More information about creating profiles is available here: http://gitbook.civicrm.org/organising-your-data/profiles.html

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are mainly interested in is having people sent to their User Dashboard on login. This is something that needs to be done in WordPress by one of a variety of plugins. As it is not a CiviCRM functionality, and there are many ways to do it in WordPress, no one has bothered to create a CiviCRM recipe for doing it.

Step 1: Create the CiviCRM User Dashboard

Create a User Dashboard in WordPress by creating a new post, clicking on the CiviCRM icon, then selecting User Dashboard, Insert Form, then Publish. This creates a page that will have the same URL for everyone, but will display the relevant content to each user about themselves. You should restrict the visibility of this post to users in a certain role by using one of a number of plugins, for example, https://wordpress.org/plugins/restrict-content/

Step 2: Redirect WordPress Users to their Dashboard when they login

Again, this is done using one of number of available redirect plugins in WordPress. A simpler one is https://wordpress.org/plugins/peters-login-redirect/